# LIllipop bug: System broadcasts "ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER" multiple times (not just once, like it should)

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a BroadcastReceiver listening for calendar event notifications, what means I am listening for CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER broadcasts. In Android 4.4 and older everything was fine - for each notification this event was broadcasted by Android OS just 1x. However, after upgrading to lollipop, looks like system now broadcasts this event at least 2x! Why? Anybody experienced it? I tested it on 2 devices (Nexus 7 and Xperia Z1 compact), here is my code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())
      Log.v("aaa", "Here we go."); // on lollipop this is called 2x, instead of 1x

    ...
    }
```

}

Anybody can confirm this? This is really annoying problem, which basically makes my app not work :)

Steps to simulate problem:

1. Create any event in calendar with a reminder/notification
2. Create and register BroadcastReceiver with code above
3. wait

Comment: Just making sure, but in your manifest, you've set it up for only one receiver, correct (not accidentally creating two)?

Comment: No, just one. You can try my code, I reproduced it on 2 devices :)

Comment: anyone found solution? I have this problem on both kitkat and lollipop

Comment: this problem does not happen in kitkat. It happens only on lollipop. ON kitkat it can happen when u have 2 calendars installed, of course then u get 2 notification...But that is not a bug. Kitkat works fine, Lollipop is buggy :)